# cx_freeze on MAC 10.9 Python 2.7.6 (32/64 bit)

Tags: eclipse, macos, wxpython, cx-freeze

I have developed an app on a Window PC using Python and wxPython.  For the several weeks I have been trying to migrate it to a MAC mini running 10.9, Python 2.7.6 (32/64 bit) using the Eclipse IDE with PyDev.  I was NOT a MAC user prior to about three weeks ago when I purchased a used Mac mini and started working on it.  Due to the fact that wxPython is a 32-bit library only I am running Python in 32-bit mode out of Eclipse - this has worked well until now I am ready to attempt and produce a stand alone app via cx_freeze and I am hitting a problem that cx_freeze is building the bundle using the 64-bit Python and it will not work with my 32-bit wx_Python library.

My question is what can I do at this point in time?  Obviously, if I had been smart I would have installed the 32-bit ONLY version of Python 2.7.6 (hind sight you know), but I did not.  I have gone through all the write to /Library/Preferences/com.apple.python.preference file and setting environment variables only to learn that that does not apply except to Apple installs.  One solution would be to install the 32-bit ONLY Python - scared I will mess my current development environment up so that is why I am asking here for help.  Also, there may be a setting in cx_freeze to accomplish this too.  Any help to a "green horn" MAC person would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to make sure that cx_Freeze is installed in the 32-bit version of Python, and that you're using that version when you freeze it.

Comment: Thomas, I have downloaded cx_freeze-4.3.2 source code from sourceforge to my mini and when I execute "sudo python setup.py build" I get an errors ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 ... How do I build a 32-bit cxfreeze from source code is my real question ???  Thanks for replying.

Comment: When you install it, make sure you're running the 32 bit Python. I don't know where it gets installed on a Mac, but run `sudo /path/to/32bit/python setup.py install`. You can check sys.maxsize to see whether you have 32-bit or 64 bit Python: http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys#sys.maxsize

Comment: Thomas, I believe I am using 32-bit python.  I have the output from my python setup.py build - I tried adding it to this list, but the list stated it looked like code and needed to be indented properly.  Would it be possible to e-mail ny capture to you directly?  I can not believe I am so close with my app but I am having so much trouble with cx_freeze.  I certainly appreciate your help.

Comment: Thomas, I see that SO does not favor, or support, direct e-mail or messaging.  I do not mind exposing my e-mail address - it is ben-robinson@nc.rr.com in an effort to get some help and make progress on my app.  I do not believe any recruiters will be coming after me :-). Hope to hear from you.

Comment: The easiest thing with code and logs is to put them in a pastebin such as [Gist](https://gist.github.com/), and post a link to them.